# Poetry: How to update the "joblib" under dependencies "scikit-learn"

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, machine-learning, data-science, python-poetry

**How to update the joblib to 1.2.1. Usually in Package.json as the work around Resolution is being used to add the packages with specific version. Similarly do we have any such provision in Poetry.**

**Github vulnerability**

joblib (pip)   |  Affected versions < 1.2.0  |  Patched version 1.2.0

poetry show scikit-learn

---

name         : scikit-learn
version      : 1.2.1
description  : A set of python modules for machine learning and data mining

dependencies

- joblib >=1.1.1
- numpy >=1.17.3
- scipy >=1.3.2
- threadpoolctl >=2.0.0

Tried:  **poetry update joblib@1.2.0**

Comment: Use `poetry add joblib@latest`.

Comment: this add the new joblib package. I want to update on the sklearn dependency package.